# Column of type date will not display, "undefined method `to_formatted_s' for nil:NilClass" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying database data from a model called Show that has columns:

```
id: integer, title: string, show_date: date, description: text, ticket_cost: string, location: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime
```

The controller accesses each Show instance via:

```
@shows = Show.all.order(:show_date)
```

And the view displays the information using:

```
<% @shows.each do |show| %>
    <h4><%= show.title %></h4>
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><%= show.location %></h5>
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span><%= show.show_date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal) %></h5>
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><%= show.ticket_cost %></h5>
    <h5><%= show.description %></h5>
<% end %>
```

All of the show information (title, location, ticket_cost, description) is displaying on the view page but the date does not display, giving the error "undefined method `to_formatted_s' for nil:NilClass". Rails console shows date values for the show_date column so the value is not nil. Additionally, the shows are being ordered correctly by date, but the date itself will not display?

Edit: Added a line before show.title:

```
<%= debug show %>
```

Which displays debug information for each instance before printing the values to the screen. One instance does not have a date but all others do, and even for instances that have a non-nil date, the date is not displaying. An example of the debug information for one of the instances is:

```
--- !ruby/object:Show
raw_attributes:
  id: 3
  title: Show 3
  show_date: 2017-03-05
  description: Show 3 description
  ticket_cost: "$3"
  location: Show 3 location
  created_at: &2 2017-02-05 21:19:15.000000000 Z
  updated_at: &4 2017-02-05 21:19:15.000000000 Z
attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash
    delegate_hash:
      id: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: id
        value_before_type_cast: 3
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Type::Integer
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 4
          range: !ruby/range
            begin: -2147483648
            end: 2147483648
            excl: true
        original_attribute: 
      title: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: title
        value_before_type_cast: Show 3
        type: &1 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::MysqlString
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 255
        original_attribute: 
      show_date: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: show_date
        value_before_type_cast: 2017-03-05
        type: !ruby/marshalable:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          :__v2__: []
          []: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime
            precision: 0
            scale: 
            limit: 
        original_attribute: 
      description: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: description
        value_before_type_cast: Show 3 description
        type: !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Type::Text
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 65535
        original_attribute: 
      ticket_cost: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: ticket_cost
        value_before_type_cast: "$3"
        type: *1
        original_attribute: 
      location: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: location
        value_before_type_cast: Show 3 location
        type: *1
        original_attribute: 
      created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: created_at
        value_before_type_cast: *2
        type: !ruby/marshalable:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          :__v2__: []
          []: *3
        original_attribute: 
      updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Attribute::FromDatabase
        name: updated_at
        value_before_type_cast: *4
        type: !ruby/marshalable:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          :__v2__: []
          []: *3
        original_attribute: 
new_record: false
active_record_yaml_version: 1
```

Comment: ok, so the one that doesn't have the date is what is causing the bug-as-stated-in-your-question... it will kill the entire page. That's why you need `try`. However - to figure out why the other dates aren't showing... we need more information. For instance - does your model do anything special with show_date ? is the and overriding method in your model (for example)? If so, can you show us that code? can you search across your codebase for `show_date` to see if something else special is done to it anywhere?

Comment: @TarynEast In the chaos of trying a million things something worked and I'm not sure what it was, but I'm thinking it was from editing the one entry that did not have a date. Thank you for all your help, much appreciated

Comment: hehe - don't you just love fixes like that... "I don't know what I fixed, but it's working now, so I'll just back away slowly..." :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that sometimes your date really is nil... this can sometimes happen with old, test data hanging around. You can temporarily get around this by using try eg:

```
show.show_date.try(:to_formatted_s, :long_ordinal)
```

This will help you stop seeing this bug... and maybe get some more details of what is going on with your data that's causing the problem.

I'd also recommend adding some logging statements so you can see the data better (just while you're bugfixing)... eg:

```
<%= @shows.inspect %>
```

to see all the data you're getting and possibly spot the bad one.

Comment: I have tried the try(:to_formatted_s, :long_ordinal) method, in which case the information just does not display but at least the view loads instead of throwing an error. I added some debug statements which I included as an edit to my original post but am still stuck. Thanks for your suggestions so far!

Comment: Yes... that's what the try will do - it will allow the bug to temporarily stop happening while you are debugging - so that you can then do some debugging. Definitely won't fix bad-data (if that's the problem) :)